# javascript click tracker, ahref links 

Tags: javascript, function, onclick, flat-file

i have a script that produces dynamic links for swf files....

eg the script will produce

```
<a href=" { url } / swf / file . swf ">Click File</a>
```

when they click the link it opens the swf file in a lightbox so i cannot use php, as its client side

i can change script so that it will add

```
onClick="javascript: FUNCTION;"
```

how would i word a javascript function to write to a file in base directory named

'click-log.txt' with href of link and timestamp...

lets say the link clicked has the url

```
http://example.com/data/swf/file1.swf
```

i would like the logfile written as

```
1329849120 , 82.**.***.*** , /data/swf/file1.swf
```

i presume its easier to write the full file path, but i would be happy with just the filename, or even the full url, if it is easiest....

i have coded this to work with php on page load many times, but cannot write javascript to do this action.....

thanks guys

Comment: If I understand you clearly, you are trying to write a file to your server via javascript? It is not possible...

Comment: don't know exactly what you are trying to do but you'll need to post the click back to the server to write the text log.

Comment: i thought that javascript would be the language to use..... as its client side that the user click a link..... is ther another coding language that would be able to perform the file write i need?

Comment: @ asken, would that be ajax, to open a request for the php file that will write the file? i can easily write a php file to do this, if there is a way to load the php script thru ajax with url like this? '/basedir/click-log.php?url= { url of link clicked } '

Comment: Please remove the "SOLVED" tag from your title and post a new answer below, instead of editing your question.

Comment: it wont let me answer my own question for 8 hours, sorry

Comment: Please remember to do that when the time permits.

Comment: done :) and i need to type more.... no 1 word comments :cry:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this goes in head (ajax request)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function clickLog(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","click-log.php?url="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

this opens 'click-log.php' with url parameter 'str' <<< 'str' is defined as 'this.href' in the onclick function brackets

```
<a href=" { url } / file .swf " onClick="clickLog(this.href)">Click Me</a>
```

when the link is clicked it opens and processes the php file, with the link href (this.href) as the parameter url=

the script even came with this.....

```
<div id="txtHint"></div>
```

if you place this div below the link to be clicked, it will echo whatever the click-log.php outputs......

this will be explained below....

this is my php file

```
<?php

$url = $_GET['url'];

$time = date('U');

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$fp = fopen('click-log.txt', 'a');
$fwrite = fwrite($fp, $time.' , '.$ip.' , '.$url.'
');

// --- echo 'Log Written'; --- // 

?>
```

this writes to end of text file 'click-log.txt' with the timestamp, ip, and href of link clicked

the echo line that is commented out, will insert the text "Log Written" into the "txtHint" div once the link has been clicked and the ajax request processed

all files used are in the base directory however anyone who would like to implement this script on their site would probably already know how to change file locations etc

....

..... thanks for the info guys.... another successful script :)

ps, now to write the script to show me the logfile in pretty graphs and pie charts :lmao:

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is a client side language, it is executed on the client's (visitors) computer, for this kind of logging you should use a server side language like PHP to create a log file on your webserver. You can try looking at this web-site for a simple log function.

http://svidhya.wordpress.com/2008/02/01/creating-and-writing-log-files/

Comment: as i stated in my question i have written many scripts to write to logfile in php, but dont know how to call the client side event, to load the script without refreshing the page or displaying anything, with the url parameter of the link clicked

Comment: You can use ajax to trigger the php file which will create the log file. I hope this example helps :)
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/simple-ajax-php-and-javascript

Comment: thanks, found an easier tutorial @ http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_ajax_database.asp ..... script written and now implemented on website :) thought javascript would do it, but now i know about ajax im going to use it quite alot :)

Comment: Nice, If I could be some kind of help I am glad maybe you should consider upvoting at least :)

Comment: was thinking about it, and not bein an a** but the first answer you posted was unhelpful and should really be downvoted for you not reading the question.... i explained that i can write to file via php easily i just needed the client side script for how to launch the php script without reloading the page

Comment: upvoted for the ajax suggestion, im sure the comment itself is enough for you to know what i meant lol